# Get number of times a negative sequence occurred in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter, numbers

Suppose I have the following array:

```
const arr = [-1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -2];
```

And I want to get the number of times negative numbers showed up sequentially, as a set together. So for the above example It would output `2` because we got `-1, -2, -1,` once and then `-1, -2` again.

Sure I could probably do something like `arr.filter(x => x < 0).length;` to get the total number of times the negative one occurred which would give me `5` but I don't want that. I want how many times a **set** of negative numbers occurred.

Comment: loop, every time the sign changes to negative, increment.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the change of not negative previous value `a` and positive actual value `b`.

```js
let array = [-1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -2],
    count = array.reduce((s, b, i, { [i - 1]: a = 1}) =>
        s + (a >= 0 && b < 0),
    0);

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in different ways, I will propose the solution that is cool because it takes advantage of how JS works, and we can solve it graphically:)

```
    arr
       //get rid of all non-negative numbers and change them to a white space
       .map(x => x < 0 ? x : ' ')
       //change it to string in order to...
       .join('')
       //replace any white spaces cluster to a single white space
       .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
       //split on these single spaces
       .split(' ')
       //get rid of a single empty string which would appear if we had an empty array
       .filter(x => x)
       //return the number of negative number clusters
       .length
```